# Position absolute в браузере самсунг

Tags: адаптивная-верстка

Имеется телефон Самсунг со стандартным самсунговским браузером. Есть блок с абсолютным позиционированием относительно блока, назначенного родителем. Проблема: этот абсолютно-десантныионированный блок просто не отображается.

UA: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; ru-ru; GT-I9060 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

Comment: ссылку дайте, где посмотреть можно. и пример кода желательно бы

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Браузер стандартный = Android Safari Mobile (и такой был одно время) = (по движку) Apple Safari, в коем тоже такая же проблема была. Решилась указанием координаты по второй оси